# Writing a macro to paste an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Im trying to paste an array I created , I run the macro and there seems to be no problem, just that the array is not pasted at all!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Worksheets("Info").Range("A1").Select
Dim iLastRow As Long
iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim arrmatrix() As String
ReDim arrmatrix(1 To iLastRow)
For i = 1 To iLastRow
Range("A2").Cells(i, 1).Select
 If Selection.Offset(11, 0) = "Pi emitida" Then
arrmatrix(i) = Range("A2").Cells(i, 1).Value
End If
Next i
Worksheets("Inicio").Range("G4").Value = arrmatrix()


End Sub
```

Comment: Are there any errors or does it just fail silently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It is not clear why you have this as a `worksheet_change` event macro
- Resize the destination range to be the same size (and shape) as the array
- Declare the array as type variant, not string, unless you want to write it element by element.
- If the destination range is a column, you will need to either transpose the array; or declare it as a 2D array and fill the first dimension:

---

```
ReDim arrmatrix(1 To iLastRow, 1 to 1)
...
arrmatrix(i,1) = Range("A2").Cells(i, 1).Value
...
Worksheets("Inicio").Range("G4").Resize(ubound(arrmatrix,1)).Value = arrmatrix()
...
```

---