# Index notation to paste an array on a range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

The following code is within a module

```
Option Explicit

Private sub paste_arr()
    Dim arr(2)
    
    arr(0) = 2
    arr(1) = 3
    arr(2) = 5

    with sh_array
   
        .Range(.Cells(2,5), .Cells(4,5)) = arr

    end with
```

Results in the following array

```
 2
 2
 2
```

It seems that only the first item in the list is pasted but I want to paste the entire array.

Other solutions don't seem to use the index notation. For example the following
[Using multiple dimension array's with sheet names instead of code names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51996487/4465153) or [A1 notation in combination with .resize()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29925038/4465153)

Edit:
Based on the answers given I don't think everybody understood my wish to use Index notation *Cells(1,1)* Instead of A1 notation *"A1"*. Here a link of what I mean with index notation / referring with index numbers. [Index numbers VBA Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-cells-by-using-index-numbers).
The wish to use index notation leads to another (perhaps not so straightforward) notation. Because a .Resize() function with index notation like:

```
With sh_array

    .Range(*code*).Resize(*code*)
    ' or
    .Range(.Cells(1,1).Resize(*code*)

end With
```

Results in a

> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' Failed

Comment: Try `.Range(.Cells(2,5), .Cells(4,5)) = Application.Transpose(arr)`. `arr` is a `1D` array and it does not have rows. In your way, only the first array element was pasted three times... When you use a bigger array, in order to avoid manually building the necessary string to paste, you can use `.Range("E2").Resize(ubound(arr) +1,1)=Application.Transpose(arr)`. + 1 because of 1D zero based array. It should work in this case, too. Or build a 2D array from the begining...

Comment: ^^ Either that or use `Dim arr(2, 0)` to indicate you want to create three rows and a single column. Then use `arr(0, 0) = 2` etc.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks for your suggestion. I have added it as an answer. However I find the resize option interesting. Is this also possible with the use of index notation? .Range("E2").Resize(ubound(arr) +1,1)=Application.Transpose(arr)
Nevermind got it by using .Cells instead of .Range. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, it is possible, if I correctly understood what you mean... If you will use a 2D array, built on the flay (not knowing from the beginning its dimensions), you can use Range("A1").resize(ubound(arr), ubound(arr, 2)).value = arr`. Where `ubound(arr, 2)` is the number of array columns. I mean when it has been resized according to some conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @FaneDuru

I was mistakenly assuming that Excel would figure out that that passing a 1 Dimensional array vertically it would adjust the array for me.

So the answer is

```
Option Explicit

Private sub paste_arr()
    Dim arr(2)
    
    arr(0) = 2
    arr(1) = 3
    arr(2) = 5

    with sh_array
   
        .Range(.Cells(2,5), .Cells(4,5)) = Application.Transpose(arr)
        ' or better if length of array is unknown
        .Range(.Cells(2,5), .Cells(UBound(arr) + 2,5)) = Application.Transpose(arr)
        ' next option based on .resize
        .Cells(2,5).Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(arr)

    end with
```

Results in the following array

```
 2
 3
 5
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1D Array to a Range

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub ZeroBased()
    
'    ' 1. Either
'    'Dim arr(2) As Variant
'    ' More correct is (Option Base related):
'    Dim arr(0 To 2) As Variant ' ensure zero-based

'    arr(0) = 2
'    arr(1) = 3
'    arr(2) = 5

    ' 2. Or
    'Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array(2, 3, 5)
    ' More correct is (Option Base related):
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = VBA.Array(2, 3, 5) ' ensure zero-based

    Dim cCount As Long
    'cCount = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1 ' 2 - 0 + 1 = 3
    ' Since in this case LBound(arr) is 0, you can simplify:
    cCount = UBound(arr) + 1 ' 2 + 1 = 3
    
    ' A simple way to write the values to the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
    Debug.Print Join(arr, ",") ' delimited
    Debug.Print Join(arr, vbLf) ' one below the other
    
    ' Write to a range
    With Sheet1
        ' Write to a one-row range:
        .Range("A1").Resize(, cCount).Value = arr ' A1:C1 ' note the comma
        ' Write to a one-column range:
        .Range("A3").Resize(cCount).Value = Application.Transpose(arr) ' A3:A5
    End With
    
    ' .Resize(, cCount) is short for .Resize(1, cCount)
    ' .Resize(cCount) is short for .Resize(cCount, 1)
    
    ' Interestingly, you could easily write only the first 2 items
    ' (think first 100 out of 1000 items):
    With Sheet1
        ' Write to a one-row range:
        .Range("E1").Resize(, 2).Value = arr ' E1:F1 ' note the comma
        ' Write to a one-column range:
        .Range("A7").Resize(2).Value = Application.Transpose(arr) ' A7:A8
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added clarification what I mean with index notation. Your suggestion uses *"A1"* notation so not what I was looking for. Thanks for the response either way. I already added my solution before yours was posted.